# How do you simplify rational expressions inside an absolute valued argument of a natural logarithmic function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate an indefinite integral and this implicit solution came up on integral-calculator.com:

[image]

I was wondering how the common denominator of the two terms inside the absolute value argument of the natural log vanished. Is there any explanation to this?

Answer (score 2):

The common denominator didn't exactly "vanish". Instead, note that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4} + 1} + \frac{x}{2}\right|\right) & = 2\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{\frac{x^2 + 4}{4}} + \frac{x}{2}\right|\right) \\
& = 2\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{\frac{x^2 + 4}{4}} + \frac{x}{2}\right|\right) \\
& = 2\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 4}}{2} + \frac{x}{2}\right|\right) \\
& = 2\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\left|\sqrt{x^2 + 4} + x\right|\right) \\
& = 2\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \ln\left(\left|\sqrt{x^2 + 4} + x\right|\right)\right) \\
& = 2\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{x^2 + 4} + x\right|\right) - 2\ln(2)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

The "C" in the first line is an arbitrary constant, and is not the same value as the $C$ in the second line. If you call the first $C$ a different name, say $C_1$, and the second one $C_2$, you can see from \eqref{eq1A} that

$$C_2 = C_1 - 2\ln(2) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

In other words, the common denominator value, i.e., $-2\ln(2)$, was "absorbed" into the arbitrary constant $C$ in the second line.